# How to get the active page name inside the app.coponent.ts file in ionic 3

Tags: typescript, ionic3

Is there any method in ionic to get current active page name inside the app.component.ts file without writing code in any other pages.

Comment: What do you mean by Any Active page?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same requirement. In my case it was for navigating to particular page when push notification is tapped. So here is how i implemented in app.component.ts:-

```
          let activeNavPages = this.app.getActiveNav().getViews();
          let rootPage:any;
          let activePage:any;

            for(var i=0; i<activeNavPages.length;i++){
              let pageName = this.app.getActiveNav().getViews()[i].name;
              if(i == 0){
                rootPage = pageName;
              }
              if(i == (activeNavPages.length-1)){
               console.log("Loop completed. Start the logic now.");
                activePage = pageName;
                console.log("Active page is :: "+ activePage+" and its Root page is :: "+ rootPage);
                if(activePage == "HomePage"){
                  console.log("Home page");
                }else{
                  console.log("Some other page");
                }

              }else{
                console.log('pageName for index  : '+i+" is "+ pageName);
              }
            }
```